# How to print YouTube OpenGraph property with colon?

Tags: php, youtube, facebook-opengraph

I need help printing a YouTube OpenGraph key, `video:url`, using the PHP [OpenGraph](https://github.com/scottmac/opengraph) library.

In the following code, the `foreach` loop works and so does `$graph->site_name` but `$graph->video:url` does not.

```
<?php
    require_once('OpenGraph.php');

    $graph = OpenGraph::fetch('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6hoBp7Hk-A');
    print $graph->site_name;
    print $graph->title;
    print $graph->video:url;
    /*
    foreach ($graph as $key => $value) {
        print "$key => {$value}<br />";
    }
    */
?>
```

The above code reproduces the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in line 7

How can I directly access the value for `video:url` and other YouTube properties with `:` using the OpenGraph object?

Comment: I've translated your post best I can, please try to use English, or use a translator yourself. (also, your error might be a missing colon `:`, or you meant to use `->`)

Answer (score 0):

Although YouTube returns a `video:url` property, you cannot retrieve it using OpenGraph as `$graph->video:url` but you can retrieve it using `$graph->__get('video:url')`. Explanation follows which examines [the OpenGraph.php code](https://github.com/scottmac/opengraph/blob/master/OpenGraph.php).

**Valid Function Names**

`$graph->video:url` will not work because PHP does not allow `:` characters in function names. The following is from the [PHP Manual: User-defined functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php):

> A valid function name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: [a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*.

**__get() Magic Method**

In the OpenGraph object for a YouTube video, the `->site_name` and `->title` properties are provided by the [`__get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) magic method which return the value matching the method name in the private `->_values` associative array. Because the `video:url` associative array key does not conform to a valid function name, you cannot access it directly. Also, because the `->_values` array is private, you cannot access it as an array. However, since the `__get()` magic method is public, you can access it directly like so:

```
$graph->__get('video:url')
```

Links:

- [PHP Manual: Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)
- [PHP Manual: User-defined functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)
- [OpenGraph.php source code](https://github.com/scottmac/opengraph/blob/master/OpenGraph.php)